# Align 2 images, one to right other to left inside div

Tags: css, html

I have a  in my webpage which carries 2 images. I want one image to be aligned left and other to the right end of the division.

The [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbekW/)

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<img id ="ttl" src="Home_files/images/ttl.png">
<img id ="se" src="Home_files/images/se.png">
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.header {
position: relative;
top: 0%;
height: 20%;
}
/*Header CSS*/
img#ttl {
position: relative;
top:50%;
height: 50%;
left: 0px;
}
img#se {
position: relative;
top:60%;
height:30%;
vertical-align:right;
margin-right: 2%;
}
```

PS: I tried `float:right;`. Its works in in Chrome and FF but not in IE.
And ofcourse this div has a parent div. But I don't think that will be a problem.

Comment: You want images on top left and top right of the page?

Comment: no...bottom left and bottom right of the division, not of the entire page..

Comment: Vertical means from top to bottom. There is no `right` in a `vertical-align`. Just a heads up ;)

Comment: Float should work if you have ie8 or higher. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/

Comment: @CaptainCarl: yeah...i was just desperately trying to fix it...

Comment: @Marco..I have IE10 and still its messing it up..

Comment: Well it's still IE i guess. "Unreliable since 1995."

Comment: @tumchaaditya `.header {display:inline}` has any effect on this?

Comment: @user1671639: have not tried...Mr. Alien's solution worked for me..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap the images inside a position relative container and use `position: absolute;` to position them to bottom left and bottom right

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MmM9r/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" />
    <img src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" />
</div>

div.wrap {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap img {
    border: 1px solid blue;
     position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.wrap img:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 0;
}

.wrap img:nth-of-type(2) {
    right: 0;
}
```

> Note: Am using `nth-of-type` to select images so that I don't have to
>   declare classes for each image, if you want to support older browsers,
>   you need to add class for each image and replace `:nth-of-type` with
>   those classes

Comment: envy... it can't be else, because this should be de perfect answer for the question

Comment: @tumchaaditya It is perfect, don't know how that fails for you

Comment: got this to work with a small rectification...apparently, IE cannot recognize the `nth-of-type(1) in CSS`...so I put IDs for images and now it works...and the most funny part is my IE10 does not even open jsfiddle correctly!! :D

Comment: @tumchaaditya Oh yes, you can remove them and use classes instead :), this way they will be cross browser

Comment: Can you just add this info to your answer?

Comment: using positions is necessary? and also nth-of-type? float property is supported in all major browsers??? -1

Comment: @Dhamu Did you even read his question? He needs image to bottm left and bottom right, do you do that with floats? Understand the question, take back your upvote cuz the answer is perfect

Comment: @Dhamu Never read half things :) Did you saw the negative voted answer below? what was the difference between his and your solution?

Comment: Works well for me, thank you! Is there any way to set the height of the div.wrap to the height of the largest image (automatically)?

Comment: Tried the JSFiddle, added a <a href> around the second image and it changed its position to be under/over the first image. I guess it is because of the nth-of-type. Any suggestions? What I want is this but with links to the images.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="left"><img id ="ttl" src="Home_files/images/ttl.png"></div>
    <div class="right"><img id ="se" src="Home_files/images/se.png"><div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left{
  float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLrYr/)

Comment: this is still true but floating does not work in all browsers and ie in particular.

Comment: He wants images on bottom left and bottom right of the division

Answer (score 0):

I used a `table` in a basic HTML header `div` for an email. It worked fine. In `tr`, had one image on left as `td` and another on right with `float: right` in another `td`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for contributing. When writing answers, it is easier to understand if you write them in the context of the question and you show some code. This question is talking about a `div` on a website, but you mentioned a `table` in an email. Also, the accepted answer using relative positioning is the proper answer for non-tabular data.