# Laying out Images in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm super bad/newb when it comes to HTML/CSS so this is probably super easy. How do you layout four images like this? -

[image]

I'm using four div tags right now to do it (or shall I say attempt?).

```
 div.imageBlockA {
     float: top;
     float: left;
 }
 div.imageBlockB {
     float: top;
     float: right;
 }
 div.imageBlockC {
     float: bottom;
     float: left;
 }
 div.imageBlockD {
     float: bottom;
     float: right;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align 2 images, one to right other to left inside div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603884/align-2-images-one-to-right-other-to-left-inside-div)

Comment: There is no `float:top` or `float:bottom`. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the heads up! I didn't know! I don't really know much html/css (specialty lies in c/c++/objective-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your layout, try the following:

```css
.image {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  }
.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgnZ-1mZ2Q2jRN2OZ2HIMESBjOfC295h0cZ_Bzgk9c30HRUR59eg">
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgnZ-1mZ2Q2jRN2OZ2HIMESBjOfC295h0cZ_Bzgk9c30HRUR59eg">
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgnZ-1mZ2Q2jRN2OZ2HIMESBjOfC295h0cZ_Bzgk9c30HRUR59eg">
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgnZ-1mZ2Q2jRN2OZ2HIMESBjOfC295h0cZ_Bzgk9c30HRUR59eg">
</div>
```

You'll need to add some more styling to make it look the way you want, but there's one way of achieving a basic layout that you're describing.

As rightfully pointed out in comment below, try also adding `box-sizing: border-box` so you can safely add padding / border to the outer div element without worrying about the extra width / height it will add (possibly breaking the layout by making the next image go to the next line as the width will then be over 50%).

EDIT - forgot to mention and as @Paulie_D pointed out in comments on your question, there isn't a `top` or `bottom` value for the `float` property.

Comment: Expanding on this, try also adding padding and box-sizing:border-box: to the .image class (to stop images touching).

Comment: @MatthewLymer was just about to edit my own answer with more on this :-) bear with me

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="image">IMAGE</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="image">IMAGE</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class="image">IMAGE</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="image">IMAGE</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Regardless of what some people may say, I find that using the table tag along with separate table rows and fields reduces the amount of work that you have to do when doing layouts. You may not agree with this method, but it's often useful - especially when starting out with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be

```css
body {
  
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="image">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgnZ-1mZ2Q2jRN2OZ2HIMESBjOfC295h0cZ_Bzgk9c30HRUR59eg">
</div>
<div class="image">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgnZ-1mZ2Q2jRN2OZ2HIMESBjOfC295h0cZ_Bzgk9c30HRUR59eg">
</div>
<div class="image">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgnZ-1mZ2Q2jRN2OZ2HIMESBjOfC295h0cZ_Bzgk9c30HRUR59eg">
</div>
<div class="image">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgnZ-1mZ2Q2jRN2OZ2HIMESBjOfC295h0cZ_Bzgk9c30HRUR59eg">
</div>
```

this uses `text-align: center;` and in some cases is this more flexible.